# 13.10 XRDP problem with gnome-fallback

Tags: gnome, 13.10, xrdp

I have an issue with `xrdp` being unable to display gnome fallback session in 13.10 - connection works fine but everything I get is Xserver grey screen and X cursor.

My hardware config is ATI HDMI with dual display on ATI drivers.

What I have done until now:

- Installed `xrdp` (no `tightvnc`), gnome-session-fallback from terminal.
- Created `.xsession` file in my home dir:
- `gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback`
- Restarted `xrdp` several times, restarted Ubuntu

At the moment file is owned by the user I am trying to connect as and has executable privilegs.

What I get after connection from Windows 8.1 laptop is Xserver grey desktop and no chance to play.

`.xsession-errors` says:

```
Xsession: Xsession started for at ....

X error of failed req: BadValue (Integer param out of range)

Major opcode for failed req: 109 (X_changeHosts)

Value in failed req: 0x5

...

gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension

gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256

gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension

gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
```

I have already reinstalled system like 20 time to solve some issues but being unable to RDP is a no go for me.

When I installed `xfce4` it was working fine. What's wrong with my gnome-fallback?

Comment: This question should be reopened. The problem is not specific to a development version of Ubuntu - I have it right now with 14.04.

Comment: @ReinierPost This post was closed as a bug, not a development release. If you are experiencing this problem please make sure your system is up to date as this bug was fixed in 14.04. If you still experience this problem please post a new question and consider submitting a bug report. Thanks!

Comment: It was *not* fixed in 14.04.  Perhaps this is due to my upgrading from12.04.  I will try it with a fresh install ... one day.

Answer (score 8):

[Lauchpad Bug #1251281](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1251281)

seems to be related with this issue - user208193, please add yourself as "Affects to me" if you agree.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please don't add comments as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, or to add actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues. If you have a new question please [ask it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 4):

Gnome-fallback package seems to be broken.... 
You could still use xrdp if you install an alternative desktop environment.. We have installed xfce desktop instead of gnome-fallback and we can perform xrdp connection to Ubuntu 13.10

a good explanation can be found at http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=4448

might be a good idea to fill in a bug report for xrdp, gnome-fallback and Ubuntu 13.10

For people using vnc software, they might encounter the same issue... Same solution here, need to install xfce and have the ./vnc/.Xstartup file modified in order to use the xfce desktop... inside the file add something like startxfce4 &

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that!
I spend hours pointlessly trying to get it to work.
The strange thing is that the gnome flashback works from the ubuntu machine, but does not from xrdp.
I didn't want to use xfce4 as I read somewhere it is not a best idea to mix desktop environments on one system.
Do you think that maybe there are some PPAs with gnome session fallback more recent builds (fixed)?
I kind of like this env and xfce4 is not really my type ;-)
Thanks
Adam

Comment: So, my question is that if I use fce instead and the bug is fixed... how do I go back??

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using xfce? it's not as good as unity

Comment: ermagawd i thought it was something I broke..... lemme try xfce