# Ubuntu 14.x with xfce4-session desktop - Terminates abruptly

Tags: xfce, xrdp

I am setting up Ubuntu 14.x to use XRDP so that I can use RDP clients to use my computer.

I saw several articles which state clearly that you cannot use gnome sessions for this. And a work around is to install XFCE4 and use that instead.

I followed these steps: http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5305

I have this working on two other boxes with exact same versions just fine. Same version of Ubuntu and all updates are installed.

But for one of my boxes, the RDP session shows the desktop for a second then POOF it terminates me.

Here is the `uname -a` for the box: `Linux xx-vbox1 3.13.0-30-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 4 21:40:53 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

And here is `lsb_release -a` results:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

`.xsession` has contents `xfce4-session`

And `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini` has contents:

```
[globals]
bitmap_cache=yes
bitmap_compression=yes
port=3389
crypt_level=low
channel_code=1
max_bpp=24
#black=000000
#grey=d6d3ce
#dark_grey=808080
#blue=08246b
#dark_blue=08246b
#white=ffffff
#red=ff0000
#green=00ff00
#background=626c72

[xrdp1]
name=sesman-Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1

[xrdp2]
name=console
lib=libvnc.so
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5900
username=na
password=ask

[xrdp3]
name=vnc-any
lib=libvnc.so
ip=ask
port=ask5900
username=na
password=ask

[xrdp4]
name=sesman-any
lib=libvnc.so
ip=ask
port=-1
username=ask
password=ask

[xrdp5]
name=rdp-any
lib=librdp.so
ip=ask
port=ask3389

[xrdp6]
name=freerdp-any
lib=libxrdpfreerdp1.so
ip=ask
port=ask3389
username=ask
password=ask

[xrdp7]
name=sesman-X11rdp
lib=libxup.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
xserverbpp=24
```

Here is `/var/log/xrdp-sesman.log` when it logs me out after two attempts:

```
[20140717-09:03:19] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 7 started successfully
[20140717-09:03:20] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username irsdownloader, ip 192.168.111.137:52421 - socket: 7
[20140717-09:03:20] [INFO ] starting Xvnc session...
[20140717-09:03:20] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sessvc - xpid=6091 - wmpid=6090
[20140717-09:03:22] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username xxxdownloader, display :15.0, session_pid 6089, ip 192.168.xxx.xxx:52421 - socket: 7
[20140717-09:18:21] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 7 started successfully
[20140717-09:18:21] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username irsdownloader, ip 192.168.111.xxx:52732 - socket: 7
[20140717-09:18:21] [INFO ] starting Xvnc session...
[20140717-09:18:21] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sessvc - xpid=7457 - wmpid=7456
[20140717-09:18:23] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username xxxdownloader, display :16.0, session_pid 7455, ip 192.168.xxx.xxx:52732 - socket: 7
```

Can someone tell me why this is abruptly terminating my session like that?

I was able to use XFCE4 in x-windows session, so I am convinced it is my xrdp settings. What am I forgetting?

Possible hint:

```
[xrdp1]
name=sesman-Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
```

If I change the port to 5901 on my xrdp sesman-xvnc connection, I get an error: cannot connect. On the other boxes, i am using 5901 just fine.