# Having trouble connecting through RDP to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS instance

Tags: 14.04, windows, xrdp

I've just completed a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onto my laptop. I installed XRDP and now i'm trying to connect to that instance from my windows 8.1 desktop machine using the MSTSC application that comes with windows...

This is my laptop running Ubuntu on Hyper-V

(http://i152.photobucket.com/albums/s174/aj_draknar/20140619_072510.jpg)

When i'm connected to instance through MSTSC, this is what it looks like on my desktop machine running windows 8.1...

(http://i152.photobucket.com/albums/s174/aj_draknar/20140619_072525.jpg)

I'm assuming that the instance of ubuntu isn't configured properly to support my desktop resolution... 1920x1080...

Any help would be most appreciated...

adTHANXvance

AJ

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same issue and for the longest time I was unsuccessful getting my **Ubuntu** to work like my **Hyper-V 2008 R2 RDP to Win7, Win8** worked. 
In fact, I was so MS over the whole thing I never thought I'd get my Tablet using aRDP to connect with my RDP Services running on Server 2008 R2.

But, thanks to this post and several others I put together my simple guide to MS people going Ubuntu.

**Required reading:** 
*You probably also know that since the introduction of Unity Desktop Interface in Ubuntu you need to tweak the configuration in order to have it working. The most annoying part while using xrdp (with Ubuntu) is the fact that you have to install an alternate desktop environment.*

**Resource:** [Griffon's IT Library](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5305) running what was suggested in [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS xrdp grey screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489310/ubuntu-14-04-lts-xrdp-grey-screen)

Loaded up **Ubuntu 14.04** following the instructions from Griffon's IT Library then the magical line in terminal

**sudo gedit**

to open gedit in root edit mode

make the changes as suggested in the link [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS xrdp grey screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489310/ubuntu-14-04-lts-xrdp-grey-screen) and you now have something to work with.

THE FIX: edit /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh (as [grahaml44](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489310/ubuntu-14-04-lts-xrdp-grey-screen) wrote)

```
#. /etc/X11/Xsession
```

**`. /usr/bin/startxfce4`**

Thanks **grahaml44** for that fix.

Score one for those that know!

Now for **Round two**, I'm not done, we're finally getting things working. Let's push it to make 4 VM's in less that 20 minutes work remotely. 
*I have an addiction with my tablet to switch desktops very often while in the company of iPad users.*

Using [Griffon's IT Library](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=6046) once again *(almost have an IT Crush)* we find ourselves following yet other Ask Ubuntu members (Thanks again!!).

[ubuntu 14.04 xrdp grey](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449785/ubuntu-14-04-xrdp-grey) it was the post by "**Nobody**" and "**abrasadera**"

If you look at what **Eric Gosh** posted you'll see that the **gnome-session** just isn't going to work. I agree and my attempts which all failed confirm it.

So there you have it, **two** methods **100%** Yes they work and verified by so many others and "**Me**".

*What did you expect? Someone from Microsoft?*

I've noticed you can create multiple sessions. I think I'm going to need a bigger server now.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are facing empty desktop problem. You can try following (as from [Blank desktop when logging in via xrdp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91657/blank-desktop-when-logging-in-via-xrdp) )

```
cd /home/youruser
echo "gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d" > .xsession
sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp restart
```

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to flag this question as a duplicate of the other (with the [flag] button below this one).