# View ubuntu local desktop remotely

Tags: networking, vnc, remote

I'm just wondering we have linux ubuntu installed on one of our pc in the office and we use tightvnc to view it and I'm working remotely. How come the desktop I view from the tightvnc is different from the desktop they're viewing locally? Is there a way I can view the desktop that they are viewing as well?

I can login on one of the pc in the office by using tightvnc and use that pc again to login on the linux pc by entering ipaddress:1 on tightvnc

I tried ipaddress:0 but it said that the machine actively refused it but if i do
ipaddress:1 i can access it.

It would really help me bigtime if I can view the desktop that they are viewing. Thank You

Comment: What VNC server are you using? Is sharing enabled for the session you's like to view remotely?

Comment: i'm using tightvnc 2.7.10. how can i know if sharing is enabled on tightvnc?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [http://www.xrdp.org](http://www.xrdp.org/)/. You can remotely log into your ubuntu machine if you have xrdp installed on it.

You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Comment: i installed this and tried to access it via remote desktop using windows but i don't see anything on the screen

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you have? Maybe your company firewall is blocking the connection. xrdp is known to work fine.

Comment: yea i tried to install xrdp on our other raspberry pi and i can access the desktop fine. i'll find out what version were using and get back to you

Comment: we are using ubuntu 14.04

Comment: when i use xrdp to remote to it i can connect and when i enter the username and password it just shows me a blank screen

Comment: i checked the firewall on linux and its not active

Comment: The blank screen on Ubuntu 14.04 is a known issue. Look at these for more details and possible fixes: https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/158 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/449785/ubuntu-14-04-xrdp-grey