# Remote Desktop - RDP blank screen and aborts after disconnect

Tags: remote-desktop, mate, windows-10, raspberrypi, xrdp

Attention: I scrolled through a lot of questions and didn't find an answer, please don't mark this as duplicate! A similar question is already here, but sadly it didn't receive any answers.

I'm trying to connect from my Windows 10 PC to my Odroid XU4 and after the connections is successfully established (at least I assume so), the screen on my windows pc turns grey for a couple of seconds and then it disappears without any error message. I installed ´xrdp´ on my linux machine. Following are the 3 steps:

Insert Credentials:
[image]

Connection builds up:
[image]

Blank screen, shortly before silent abort:
[image]

**##Abort##**

**EDIT**
This is the syslog-output:

```
Oct  3 08:25:18 odroid systemd[1]: Starting Session c4 of user odroid.
Oct  3 08:25:19 odroid org.a11y.Bus[2241]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Oct  3 08:25:19 odroid org.a11y.Bus[2241]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Oct  3 08:25:19 odroid org.a11y.atspi.Registry[2283]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Oct  3 08:25:19 odroid gnome-session[2197]: gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
Oct  3 08:25:19 odroid gnome-session[2197]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
Oct  3 08:25:24 odroid gnome-session[2197]: gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
Oct  3 08:25:24 odroid gnome-session[2197]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
Oct  3 08:25:24 odroid gnome-session[2197]: x-session-manager[2197]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
Oct  3 08:25:24 odroid x-session-manager[2197]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
Oct  3 08:25:24 odroid x-session-manager[2197]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Oct  3 08:25:24 odroid gnome-session[2197]: x-session-manager[2197]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Oct  3 08:25:24 odroid org.a11y.atspi.Registry[2283]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":10.0"
Oct  3 08:25:24 odroid org.a11y.atspi.Registry[2283]: after 11 requests (11 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Oct  3 08:25:24 odroid org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[2241]: A connection to the bus can't be made
Oct  3 08:25:24 odroid org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[2241]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Oct  3 08:25:24 odroid org.a11y.Bus[2241]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
```

Comment: Did you check the logs to see if xrdp is unhappy about something.  I normally ssh into a box, then run my rdp server from that terminal, then rdp in and watch the terminal output, to see if rdp complained about anything.  If at first you don't see anything helpful, try running xrdp in a more verbose mode, and check the syslog (/var/log/syslog).

Comment: @sibaz I put the syslog output into the question. Can you guess what this means? Software acceleration process stopped? And do you think this problem could be related through an invalid port? I can remotely login an everything, but afterwards it crashes.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/453868/428973

Comment: Well, x-session-manager is failing, presumably as a result of the 'software acceleration check' failing, presumably because your hardware is using hardware acceleration, and xrdp doesn't know how to emulate that in software (at a complete guess).  o9000's comment suggests that xrdp doesn't work with unity or gnome, which seems mad, but if it's true, that'll be your problem.  I suggest you try a different vnc client or try a different window manager.  I use KDE (and kdrc/krfb) but it's not exactly small.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution, after putting this line into the terminal, it worked:

```
echo mate-session> ~/.xsession
```

If this doesn't help you, try the following command before:

```
sudo apt-get install mate-core
```

(I'm not sure but I used a pre-compiled modified ubuntu by hardkernel. Mate was the desktop envoirement, but I was able to "newly" install the mate-core, not just update the existing. Maybe this was problem.)

Comment: Isnt RDP on port 3389? Are you doing some port forwarding?

Comment: @j0h: Yes I did port forwarding. Of course you only need to do that if you need access from outside your local network.

Comment: mate-session give an error: ** (mate-session:11853): WARNING **: Cannot open display:

Comment: OH: don't use root account to access PC via RDP, create new account and use it to call mate-session

Answer (score 1):

solved:
Type the following command:

```
sudo sed -i '/allowed_users=console/allowed_users=anybody/' /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to try the parallels client:

instructions on how to obtain and install it can be found here:
http://kb.parallels.com/en/123304
  (they provide a .deb package to make you life easier. :) )

Answer (score 0):

What you see is due to [this bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=731173) in GNOME 3. You may use another desktop environment such as KDE.

Comment: This is reproducible using KDE as well